# CollectionChanged handler from ObservableCollection is null when getting item from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, events, observablecollection

We are currently working on a project and I'm working on some kind of alert/ notification system. The basic idea:

There are several Questions, each Question contains an Observable collection of Answer objects. All these items get saved to a SQL Server Database (we're using Entity Framework Code First approach). The Important parts of the Question class:

```
public class Question
{
    public Question()
    {
      ...
      Answers = new ObservableCollection<Answer>();
      ...
    }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }

    ...Extra stuff omitted
}
```

I want to add a CollectionChanged Handler to the ObservableCollection of Answer instances. I do this when I Create a Subscription object for that Question. This Subscription object gets created and saved in my manager class which communicates with the Database context. The methods which perform this:

```
public void CreateQuestionSubscription(int userId, int questionId, NotificationFrequency notificationFrequency)
{
  Regular subscriber = _politiciOnlineDbContext.Regulars.SingleOrDefault(r => r.UserId == userId);
  Question question = _politiciOnlineDbContext.Questions.SingleOrDefault(q => q.QuestionId == questionId);
  if (question == null || subscriber == null) return;

  question.Answers.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(CollectionChangedMethod);

  QuestionSubscription questionSubscription = new QuestionSubscription()
  {
    NotificationFrequency = notificationFrequency,
    Question = question,
    Subscriber = subscriber,
    WantsToReceiveEmail = true
  };
  _politiciOnlineDbContext.QuestionSubscriptions.AddOrUpdate(questionSubscription);
  _politiciOnlineDbContext.SaveChanges();
}

private void CollectionChangedMethod(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine("An answer has been added! (sub " + ((Subscription)sender).Subscriber.UserId + "-" + ((QuestionSubscription)sender).Question.QuestionId + ")");

    ((Subscription)sender).Alerts.Add(new Alert((Subscription)sender, AlertType.QuestionAnswerAdded));
  }
}
```

When I do this, the Handler does get connected to the CollectionChanged event of the ObservableCollection. But it disappears quickly, when I get the Question object from the Database the CollectionChanged event doesn't contain any handlers.

This is rather logical, because I don't see how and where they would get saved, but this is not what I want to achieve. I need the handlers to keep being connected, of course also when the objects get put in and fetched from the Database. How could I do this?

Comment: From my experence this "disconnection" happens when the ObservableCollection Property was set more than once = the instance of the collection changed and your eventhandler subscribes to the old value of the property. You could set a breakpoint to the setter of your Answers Property, or make the setter private and don't allow the Answer Collection to be initialzed more than once. To ensure that the collection object itself does not change. Another way would be to "search all references" within visual studio and look up where the setter is called.

Comment: I looked at the Usages(I think that's what you meant?) of the Answers property but it doesn't get set anywhere else. I even commented the line `Answers = new ObservableCollection<Answer>();` in the constructor of Question and gave the property a provate set, but the handler still disappears... Is it really that difficult to remember a handler on a collection? There's something with writing it to the database which screws things over, when the question is fetched it probably creates a new ObservableCollection which would mean I would need to set the handler each time it gets fetched, crazy...

Comment: Maybe you can check if it's the same instance with "GetHashCode", just to be sure that the Answer Collection didn't change meanwhile. Maybe the whole Question was "renewed" from store. Just another question: if you commented out the initalization of Answers, why it is not null?